# Java 8 version with an Ant/Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, ant, build

I have a project that build with ant 1.9.4 and java 1.8.0_121 on machine A using Jenkins. But if I move the same project to a machine with the same versions of Ant and Jenkins but with java 1.8.0_131, my build fails.
Is there a way to make an ant build succeed with any Java 8 version without installing a different version of Java 8?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that builds fail due to Jenkins issues? Maybe you got problem with your sources?
Can you attach build console output?

Comment: i am getting a JiBX exception after building on one machine but I am getting a build SUCCESS on another. The only difference is the Java version.

Comment: two ideas: 1) try building it locally with both versions or 2) post the smallest project you can that replicates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am on a Linux RHEL, I had to increase the memory size configuration for JiBx in the /etc/security/limits.conf file.